# Flutter: Hero-like widget transition for setState, without usage of Navigator

Tags: flutter

Can this animated widget replacement be done without page routes and a Stack with manual position resolving? A preview from a ListView should fly to the main position. I've done it with a Hero and Navigator.push(), but I want to do it on one screen with just `setState((){index++;})` in a stateful widget.

[image]

Comment: Yes it can be done with some effort

Comment: see `AnimatedCrossFade` (and `ScaleTransition` / `FadeTransition`  maybe)

Comment: @pskink thanks, I'll try it